# Cell navigation to GridControl

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I use **DevExpress**

I had difficulty managing. I have a GridControl and added cell navigation buttons. That's just the question, how can you implement this code?

There are 4 buttons, among which are: First entry (|<), Previous entry (<), Next entry (>), Last entry (>|). How can you programmatically write these cell movements?

An example of an Access screen, such as this navigation:

[image]

Comment: Not too familiar with GridControl, but i'm guess you want the selected item in the Grid to change on button click? So it will be something like GridControl.Selected = ...... In the four events you have created.

Comment: At each button there is a movement on cells, like the blue background goes on movement...

Comment: Use property GridView.FocusedRowHandle and change it acordinly. GridControl is just a container, use gridview within it.

Comment: Based on our discourse below I understand why you need to invent a proverbial wheel. That said, I think it would be helpful if you could at least provide any code or information on what you have done thus far.  As it stands, all someone could do for you is essentially write the code from scratch, which I doubt will happen -- especially in the time you need it for your project

Comment: There is no code, I do not know how to do this by the movement of the cell. There all other methods... And so I know from the usual DataGridView, to implement it. But from GridControl, I realize, I think how can I do... Can you help with this?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to not write it yourself...  use the Dev Express embedded navigator.

If you go to designer view on the grid, go to Feature Browser, Focus, Embedded Navigator and set the `UseEmbeddedNavigator` property to true.

[image]

You can, of course, also do this in the regular property window of your form.

Once you do that, your grid will have it:

[image]

Comment: Our of curiosity why, when it's available out of the box?

Comment: I will say briefly, I am writing a diploma.. Therefore, it must be done like this...